# How to get a text from HTML using span class in VB.NET WebBrowser?

Tags: vb.net, extract, scrape

I got the following HTML Code:

```
<span class="valor-strong">191,28</span>
```

I want to show 191,28 in a MessageBox, how can I extract it and display it?

Comment: You could use a HTML parser such as [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<span class="valor-strong" id="getMe">191,28</span>
```

**VB.NET**

```
MessageBox.Show(WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("getMe").InnerText)
```